# The question about the quasi-linear polynomial on page 162 of Arnold’s ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Recall the theorem on page 162:

> **Theorem**: *The differentiation operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, and for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ 
>   \begin{equation}\mathrm{e}^{t\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}}=H^t,\end{equation}
>   where $H^t: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is the operator of translation by $t$, i.e. $\left(H^tf\right)(x)=f(x+t)$.*

Remark that $\mathbb{R}^n$ above represents a vector space of quasi-polynomials $\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}p(x)$ (whose space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$),and where $p(x)$ is a polynomial whose degree is less than $n$.

My question is how to understand the sign $\mathrm{e}^{t\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}}$, and how this sign acts on the quasi-polynomial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that
$$
(e^{t\frac{d}{dx}}f)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(x)
$$
is the Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $x$, and that for analytical functions this is exactly $f(x+t)$, the result of the translation operator. As the space of polynomials is a subset of the space of analytical functions, this shows that the claim is true. Using polynomials avoids any convergence considerations as the series involved will be finite sums.